Google App script not getting changes made
I have deployed a new version of my app, in the new version some code has been commented and some changes were made, after saving and deploying the new deployment, executing my app still uses the previous version of my .gs script.
I have tried to create a copy of my file .gs, deleting the original and renaming the copy as the old one but still the changes have not been registered. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Please ensure that You are using the URL / version of the new deployment. If You need further help please add a [mcve]

DEPLOYING WEB APPS VERSION
Further explaining the comment of @Wicket. A possible reason the changes are not reflected in your deployment is that it may still be using the same version, or you might be accessing the same URL from old despite having created a New deployment.
When updating your Google Apps Script, it’s recommended to use the “(Test) head deployment” URL (ending with /dev) to verify that your code changes are reflected correctly. This allows you to run and test your latest code changes in real-time without creating a new version or URL.
Whenever you are using “New deployment”, you receive a new URL each time. always ensure to copy and use the updated deployment URL and check if the results with the “Test deployment” are being reflected.
Alternatively, I suggest using the “Manage deployment” and creating a new version following the steps below. This way, you can maintain the same URL while implementing changes.
SAMPLE MANAGE DEPLOYMENT:

STEPS:

Open your script project.
At the top, click Deploy > Manage deployments.
Select the active deployment to create a new version for and click
Edit.
In the Version section, select New version.
Optional: add a description
Click Deploy.

REFERENCES:

Test a web app deployment
Create a version

